# color a column based on the values of another column with formattable

Tags: r, formattable

With the formattable package, it's easy to color one column based on its own values:

```
formattable::formattable(mtcars[1:3,1:2],list(mpg=color_text("blue","red")))
```

[image]

Is there a way to color the column cyl based on the values in the column mpg instead?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See second argument under "list":

```
library(formattable)

formattable::formattable(mtcars[1:3,1:2], 
                     list(mpg = color_text("blue","red"),
                          cyl = formatter("span",
                                          style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(mtcars$mpg[1:3] == 21, "blue", "red")))))
```

> "...we define x as being the value by placing it to the left of the ~ and then use it in the function to the right (it is a lambda function, to use some jargon)"
>   [read more here](https://www.displayr.com/formattable/)